# How to define a bundle of variable-and-function pairs?

Tags: functions, list, defun, setq

I want to define a bundle of variable-and-function pairs, e.g.: `vl/path-doc` points to my often used path, and `vl/open-path-doc` is used for open it in `dired-mode`.

I tried this piece of code:

```
(setq vivo-work-directory "~/Workspace/vivo/")

(defvar vl/paths
  '((aktualoj . "doc/aktualoj/")
    (doc . "doc/")
    (analysis . "analysis/")
    (lernejo . "lernejo/")
    (utils . "utils/")
    (topics . "vivo/topics/")
    (projects . "vivo/projects/")))

(defun vl/create-path-funcs (p-list)
  (mapc
   (lambda (x)
     (let* ((s (car x))
            (p (concat vivo-work-directory (cdr x)))
            (sym-p (make-symbol (concat "vl/path-" (symbol-name s))))
            (sym-f (make-symbol (concat "vl/open-path-" (symbol-name s)))))
       (progn
         (set sym-p p)
         (set sym-f (lambda () (interactive) (dired p))))
       ))
   p-list))

(vl/create-path-funcs vl/paths)
```

Then, I hope I can use `M-x` to invoke `vl/path-doc`, `vl/open-path-doc`, etc. But I failed.

Of course, I can define these pairs one by one. But if it's OK, I can change my `vl/paths` without re-defining anything else. So, if possible, how to define the pairs of variable-and-function based on a list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`make-symbol` returns an uninterned symbol. That means you get a symbol with name, function cell, value cell, and property list but the symbol is not registered in the global `obarray`. Therefore, you cannot use it for function evaluation with the usual parenthesis notation.

If you replace `make-symbol` by `intern` the symbol is also registered in the `obarray` and you can use it in the usual way.

Furthermore, you cannot use `set` to set the symbol's function cell. You must use `fset` instead.

Last but not least I think you want the local variable `p` in the `lambda` expression be replaced by the value of `sym-p` which is itself a symbol with a name prefix `vl/path-`. You can use [back-quote notation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html) for that purpose.

```el
(setq vivo-work-directory "~/Workspace/vivo/")

(defvar vl/paths
  '((aktualoj . "doc/aktualoj/")
    (doc . "doc/")
    (analysis . "analysis/")
    (lernejo . "lernejo/")
    (utils . "utils/")
    (topics . "vivo/topics/")
    (projects . "vivo/projects/")))

(defun vl/create-path-funcs (p-list)
  (mapc
   (lambda (x)
     (let* ((s (car x))
            (p (concat vivo-work-directory (cdr x)))
            (sym-p (intern (concat "vl/path-" (symbol-name s))))
            (sym-f (intern (concat "vl/open-path-" (symbol-name s)))))
         (set sym-p p)
         (fset sym-f `(lambda () (interactive) (dired ,sym-p))))
       )
   p-list))

(vl/create-path-funcs vl/paths)
```

Comment: Note that writing `progn` within `let*` is redundant and that, under `lexical-binding`, the inner-most `lambda` does not need to be backquoted (and it is always better not to quote anonymous functions), as `sym-p` will be lexically captured by the closure.

Comment: I removed the `progn`. It was just a left-over from the copy of the OP's version. It just didn't hurt. I think `lexical-binding` would really make a new answer. But, in that case the explanation would be a bit longer.

Answer (score 1):

@Tobias nice. Here still a command making new entries:

```
(defun vl/new-pathsfunc ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((directory (read-from-minibuffer "directory: " (substring default-directory 2)))
    (name (intern (read-from-minibuffer "Name: "))))
    (unless (map-contains-key vl/paths name)
      (push (cons name directory) vl/paths)
      (vl/create-path-funcs vl/paths))))
```

Some calls to `intern` seem not necessary. Here is what works for me:

```
(defun ar-create-path-funcs (&optional pfadliste)
  (let ((pfadliste (or pfadliste ar-pfad)))
    (mapc
     (lambda (x)
       (let ((s (car x))
         (p (cdr x)))
     (fset s `(lambda () (interactive) (dired ,p) (goto-char (point-max))(skip-chars-backward " \t\r\n\f")))))
     pfadliste)))
```